# What's the "java" way of converting chars (digits) to ints

Tags: java, integer, char

Given the following code:

```
    char x = '5';
    int a0 = x - '0'; // 0
    int a1 = Integer.parseInt(x + ""); // 1
    int a2 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(x)); // 2
    int a3 = Character.digit(x, 10); // 3
    int a4 = Character.getNumericValue(x); // 4
    System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d %d", a0, a1, a2, a3, a4);
```

(version 4 credited to: [casablanca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381345/casablanca))

What do you consider to be the "*best-way*" to convert a char into an int ? ("*best-way*" ~= *idiomatic way*)

We are not converting the actual numerical value of the char, but the value of the representation.

Eg.:

```
convert('1') -> 1
convert('2') -> 2
....
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure anybody coming from those ancient C and Pascal things, like me, would vote for first option.

Comment: @Nikita: I do come from those "ancient C and Pascal things", but unless performance is absolutely critical, I would prefer a more expressive way than `x - '0'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: parse int value from a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

How about [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29)?

Answer (score 16):

I'd strongly prefer `Character.digit`.

Comment: Please explain reasoning

Answer (score 8):

The first method.  It's the most lightweight and direct, and maps to what you might do in other (lower-level) languages.  Of course, its error handling leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 4):

If speed is critical (rather than validation you can combine the result)
e.g.

```
char d0 = '0';
char d1 = '4';
char d2 = '2';
int value = d0 * 100 + d1 * 10 + d2 - '0' * 111;
```

Comment: I like the `'0' * 111` value :-)

Answer (score -1):

Convert to Ascii then subtract 48.

```
(int) '7' would be 55 
((int) '7') - 48 = 7 
((int) '9') - 48 = 9
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way to convert a character of a valid digit to an int value is below. If c is larger than 9 then c was not a digit. Nothing that I know of is faster than this. Any digits in ASCII code 0-9(48-57) ^ to '0'(48) will always yield 0-9. From 0 to 65535 only 48 to 57 yield 0 to 9 in their respective order.

```
int charValue = (charC ^ '0');
```