# Casting a char element so it can be used in an int method?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code,

```
public int deleteSubString(String delSubString) 
{
    int len = delSubString.length();
    char []temp = delSubString.toCharArray();
    char first = 0;
    temp[0] = first ;
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(len);
    return deleteSubString(first,len);
}
```

Inorder for it to work correctly the overloaded deleteSubString method in the return statment needs to take two integers to return deleteSubString( int first, int len). I can't seem to cast to an integer. Is it possible to get an integer out of the temp char array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: parse int value from a char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Comment: your question is unclear. What is the output that you expect and what is this program for..?

Comment: @Qiu the other solution dosen't work in my situation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return deleteSubString(Character.getNumericValue(first), len);
```