# What is the equivalent of the C# Convert.ToInt32 in Java

Tags: java, c#, code-translation

I am trying to translate some C# code into java and would like to know what is the java equivalent of [`System.Convert.ToInt32(char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the
>   equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

```
Convert.ToInt32(letter);
```

Comment: If you are referring to `letter` as a `char` instead of `String` per Tim's edit, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char). Either way, google the question before asking. These are found within seconds.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: `Integer.parseInt(char)` is not the same as `Convert.ToInt2(char)` for the same reason as why this implcicit conversion `int charNum = '5';` yields 53 not 5.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm aware. Prior to your edit I assumed he referred to `Convert.ToInt32(string)`. In my comment I point to an approach that parses chars using `Character.getNumericValue`.

Comment: "(int)letter" will give the same result as "Convert.ToInt32(letter)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Convert.ToInt32(someChar)" does exactly what "(int)someChar" does.
Since "(int)someChar" is available in Java, why not use that?

When testing the various options, use '5' as a test - some options will convert this simply to the integer 5, but you will want the integer 53 to match the original C# behavior of Convert.ToInt32.