# How do you get the numerical value from a string of digits?

Tags: java, arrays, string, numbers, switch-statement

I need to add certain parts of the numerical string.

for example like.

036000291453

I want to add the numbers in the odd numbered position so like

0+6+0+2+1+5 and have that equal 14.

I tried the charAt(0)+charAt(2) etc, but it returns the digit at those characters instead of adding them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to convert the string to integer then perform anything you want. Here is a link in stack:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java

Comment: If the conversion is done on the entire string, it's much harder to add individual characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: parse int value from a char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried the charAt(0)+charAt(2) etc, but it returns the digit at those
>   characters instead of adding them.

```
Character.getNumericValue(string.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `charAt` to get to get the `char` (ASCII) value, and then transform it into the corresponding `int` value with `charAt(i) - '0'`. `'0'` will become `0`, `'1'` will become `1`, etc.

Note that this will also transform characters that are not numbers without giving you any errors, thus `Character.getNumericValue(charAt(i))` should be a safer alternative.

Comment: @Winterone: if it works then click the green check button to accept his answer.

Comment: @Winterone No problem :) btw also check out `Character.getNumericValue` as suggested by Voldemort.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String s = "036000291453";

  int total = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i+=2) {
    total = total + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
  }

  System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: This will just convert the ASCII value to int. The OP wants the numerical value that the character represents.

Comment: Sorry I misread it, rewrote answer to convert each to numeric value when adding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Character.**digit()** method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "036000291453";
    int value = Character.digit(s.charAt(1), 10); 
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code loops through any number that is a String and prints out the sum of the odd numbers at the end

```
String number = "036000291453";
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i += 2) {
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));
}

System.out.println("The sum of odd integers in this number is: " + sum);
```