# Change int to string in a matrix

Tags: java, string, int

I want to convert some integers into a * based on a rule. I can determine which places in the matrix it should convert, but cannot convert it. 
I give the program the first matrix and it should return the second matrix:

```
5 4 5 5 8
5 4 6 4 1
3 4 5 4 6
7 8 4 3 6

5 4 5 5 *
5 4 * 4 1
3 4 5 4 6
7 * 4 3 6
```

my code is this:

```
for(int i=1; i<r-1; i++) {
  for(int a=1; a<c-1; a++){
    if(matrix[i-1][a] < matrix[r][a] && matrix[i+1][a] < matrix[r][a] && matrix[i][a-1] < matrix[r][a] && 
       matrix[i][a+1] < matrix[r][a]) {
      matrix[r][a] = *;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
The matrix is an int type. I can determine which locations in the matrix should be converted, however the convertion itself does not work.

I get this error: Error: Syntax error on token "*", invalid Expression

Comment: What exception do you have? Ther're many reasons.

Comment: Exactly what `int` value do you think a `*` has?

Comment: what is the `matrix` datatype?

Comment: It seems that `matrix` is `int`

Comment: i have some other code that determine the position in the matrix that should be converted. But the convertion itself does not work.

Comment: If the matrix store `int` values, you can't store string or char values. So first you need to store those numbers in a string matrix and then change them to `*`.

Comment: What "*does not work*" mean? Do you get a compile-time error? An `Exception`? Unexpected behaviour? Please be precise.

Comment: @CryogenicNeo "*If the matrix store int values, you can't store string or char values.*" - That is only partly true. `char`s can be widened to `int`.

Comment: @Turing85 I get an Exception error

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it's useless in this case because if you would convert integers into chars by their value, will be cases that values or number are replaced with `*`.

Comment: Do you get an `Exception` or an `Error`? Please [edit] your question and add the stack trace. It would also be beneficial if you mark the line throwing the `Exception`/`Error`.

Comment: @Turing85 I edited my question. It looks like an error from my compiler, but i do not have much experience.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. You should revisit some basic tutorials like [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) and familiarize yourself with primitive types and how to work with them.

Comment: `r` doesn't vary in your loop, **what** is the rule?

Comment: @Turing85 I understand that * is not an integer. I also tried .equals but that did not work too. Could I convert the whole matrix first to an string type and then replace some field with *?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch That indeed should be i

Comment: You can, yes. But you would have to create a `String[][]` and copy each value manually.

Comment: @Turing85 Okay thanks, I am going to try that. Or do you have a faster solution? (Maybe start with an string matrix)

Comment: Experiment yourself. Programming is a craft, the more you do it, the better you become.

Comment: @Turing85 Will do. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could leave `int[][] matrix`, and e.g. mark a `*` cells with some illegal number (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). And when you print or use this matrix, do like: `System.out.print(matrix[i][k] != Integer.MAX_VALUE ? matrix[i][k] : '*')`

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];
    modifyMatrix(matrix);
    print(matrix);
}

public static void modifyMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
            if (isStar(row, col, matrix))
                matrix[row][col] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

private static boolean isStar(int row, int col, int[][] matrix) {
    // TODO your condition to place a '*'
    return false;
}

private static void print(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0, max = matrix[row].length; col < msx; col++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] != Integer.MAX_VALUE ? matrix[row][col] : '*');
            System.out.println(col != max - 1 ? ' ' : '\0');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use matrix of type `Integer` instead of `int` and then mark a `*` cell with `null`

Then when printing or using matrix show `null` values with `*`

Comment: [What could possibly go wrong?](https://384uqqh5pka2ma24ild282mv-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Top10Exceptions-1.png)

Comment: @Turing85 with a simple `if` the `null` value could be checked. the benefit of `null` value is that it is always invalid value you may need any other supposed invalid value in the future such as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or others

Comment: I prefer to use `int` instead of `Integer` where is is possible

Comment: Of course. That is true for ever `null`. Yet, the `NPE` is the most prominent exception and there are languages, like Kotlin, explicitly trying to add `null`-safety.

Answer (score 0):

In an int matrix you can't put characters or symbols(like '*')

The easiest thing to do is to change the type of the matrix. You should use char instead of int.

```
  char[][] matrix = new char[r][c];
```

If you want to use an element from the matrix for equations you can use the

```
Character.getNumericValue(matrix[i][j]);
```

With this code it will return the number and if it has not numeric value it will return -1

You can check this link for the getNumericValue 
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773871/how-do-you-get-the-numerical-value-from-a-string-of-digits?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: And what if we want **numbers with more than one digit**? for example `23` this is two characters or `789` is three characters so we have to use `String` instead of `char`

Comment: The example that he gave us is only a digit. if he wants to use more than one characters he can use **String[][]** but he has to change a little the code. Instead of
      Character.getNumericValue(matrix[i][j]); 
he can use a for(int k =0; i<matrix[i][j].length; i++){
int num=0;
num+=Character.getNumericValue(matrix[i][j].charAt(k));

Answer (score 0):

you should create an new array of strings the size of your matrix.

then run trough your matrix and either add the number or change it into a string, like this:

```
public String[] convert(int[] matrix,int rule) {
    String[][] arr = new String[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    for(int i = 0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<matrix[i].length;j++) {
            if(matrix[i][j] == rule)
                arr[i][j] = "*";
            else
               arr[i][j] = String.valueOf(matrix[i][j]);
    return arr;
```