# Adding numbers together from a String

Tags: java, string, char, character, addition

I want to be able to separate a String of two numbers and then add them together, but I keep getting the `int` value of each character. If I enter "55" as a string I want the answer to be 10. How can I do that?

```
package org.eclipse.wb.swt;

import java.util.*;

public class ISBN13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("enter a string");
      String numbers = input.nextLine();  //String would be 55

      int num1=numbers.charAt(0); //5

      int num2=numbers.charAt(1); //5

      System.out.println(num1+num2); //the answer should be 10
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968343/5221346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the ascii value of the characters; you can use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-) to get the numeric value. Something like,

```
String numbers = "55";
int num1 = Character.digit(numbers.charAt(0), 10);
int num2 = Character.digit(numbers.charAt(1), 10);
System.out.println(num1 + num2);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.toCharArray()` method and then add them in a for loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            char[] charArray = line.toCharArray();
            int sum = 0;
            for (char character : charArray) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(character));
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        } finally {
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue(element.charAt(0));
```