# extracting integer at each positions from a string S

Tags: java, string

I accepted a number as string in java as S=1234 .NOW i want to get the integer values at s[0] s[1] s[2] s[3] .

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)// l is length of string s
    int x=s[i]-'0';// print this now
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What about `int x=s.charAt(i)-'0';`?

Comment: Have you tried using `Integer.valueOf()`?

Comment: `Character.getNumericValue()`...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the integer by using `charAt()` in combination of getting the numeric value of that Character.

```
// Assuming you already have the Integer object "S" declared and assigned
int[] s = new int[Integer.toString(S).length()]; // create the integer array

for(int i = 0; i < Integer.toString(S).length(); i++)
{
  int x = Character.getNumericValue(S.charAt(i));
  s[i] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java strings aren't just `char` arrays, they're objects, so you cannot use the `[]` operator. You do have the right idea, though, you're just accessing the characters the wrong way. Instead, you could use the `charAt` method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) { // l is length of string s
    int x = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    // Do something interesting with x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this information from another stack overflow response: [Java: parse int value from a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue(S.charAt(i));
```

Comment: Once you have enough reputation, you can flag questions as duplicates. Plus, the other answer already provided that solution.

Comment: Oh cool, hopefully I'll be at that point soon. I must have been working on the answer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an numerical string just by using Character.getNumericalValue() method. below is the way to get it.

```
   String num = "1234";
    char[] a=num.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        p.add(Character.getNumericValue(a[i]));
        System.out.println(p.get(i));
    }
```