# How to get an integer at a specified position in a string of integers?

Tags: java

If I have a string like `String myString = "12345"` and I want to return the value at index [0]. How do I do this? I've tried for example `int foo = myString.charAt(0)` and get a weird value like 49?

Comment: dupe of [Java: parse int value from a char](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968343/1248974)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Character.getNumericValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-):

```
String myString = "12345";
int foo = Character.getNumericValue(myString.charAt(0));
```