# How do I convert a Char to Int?

Tags: list, kotlin, character, data-conversion

So I have a `String` of integers that looks like `"82389235"`, but I wanted to iterate through it to add each number individually to a `MutableList`. However, when I go about it the way I think it would be handled:

```
var text = "82389235"

for (num in text) numbers.add(num.toInt())
```

This adds numbers completely unrelated to the string to the list. Yet, if I use `println` to output it to the console it iterates through the string perfectly fine.

How do I properly convert a `Char` to an `Int`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's because `num` is a `Char`, i.e. the resulting values are the ascii value of that char.

This will do the trick:

```
val txt = "82389235"
val numbers = txt.map { it.toString().toInt() }
```

The `map` could be further simplified:

```
map(Character::getNumericValue)
```

Answer (score 16):

Since Kotlin 1.5, there's a built-in function `Char.digitToInt(): Int`:

```kotlin
println('5'.digitToInt()) // 5 (int)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/digit-to-int.html

Answer (score 10):

The variable `num` is of type `Char`. Calling `toInt()` on this returns its ASCII code, and that's what you're appending to the list.

If you want to append the numerical value, you can just subtract the ASCII code of 0 from each digit:

```
numbers.add(num.toInt() - '0'.toInt())
```

Which is a bit nicer like this:

```
val zeroAscii = '0'.toInt()
for(num in text) {
    numbers.add(num.toInt() - zeroAscii)
}
```

This works with a `map` operation too, so that you don't have to create a `MutableList` at all:

```
val zeroAscii = '0'.toInt()
val numbers = text.map { it.toInt() - zeroAscii }
```

Alternatively, you could convert each character individually to a `String`, since `String.toInt()` actually parses the number - this seems a bit wasteful in terms of the objects created though:

```
numbers.add(num.toString().toInt())
```

Comment: `'0'.toInt()` correctly returns `48`, which as explained in the answer, is the ASCII code for the character `'0'`. If you want the numerical value of a character containing a digit, you'll have to subtract the ASCII value of `'0'` from it.

Answer (score 9):

On JVM there is efficient [java.lang.Character.getNumericValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968343/7366707) available:

```
val numbers: List<Int> = "82389235".map(Character::getNumericValue)
```

Comment: You seem to have linked to the wrong answer on that question, I've changed it if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, the zeroAscii answer can be simplified to

```
val numbers = txt.map { it - '0' }
```

as Char - Char -> Int. If you are looking to minimize the number of characters typed, that is the shortest answer I know. The

```
val numbers = txt.map(Character::getNumericValue)
```

may be the clearest answer, though, as it does not require the reader to know anything about the low-level details of ASCII codes. The toString().toInt() option requires the least knowledge of ASCII or Kotlin but is a bit weird and may be most puzzling to the readers of your code (though it was the thing I used to solve a bug before investigating if there really wasn't a better way!)

Edit: I think Andrejs' answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315079/14178883) is the best at the moment, I would only elaborate to give the full translation for the problem of the OP:

```
val text = "82389235"
val numbers = text.map { it.digitToInt() }
```

(I admit the OP wanted to add the numbers to a mutable list, in which case the last line would start with "numbers +=" instead of "val numbers =".  But since it could be that the OP mainly cared about getting the numbers into a list and had simply chosen a mutable list since a for-loop required it, I give the example in what I think is generally best practice: making variables as immutable as possible).