# What happens with toInt()

Tags: kotlin

I currently start to learn Kotlin and I was making this code

```
val a =  "1"
val b = a[0]
val c = b.toInt()
println(c)
```

When I run the code, the result is 49. What really happened? Because I think the result will be 1.

Comment: because you converting char to int and char "1" is equivalent to code 49

Comment: It's likely the ASCII value of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html), which is a [`CharSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char-sequence/index.html). That is why you can access [`a[0]`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char-sequence/get.html) in the first place. `a.get(0)` or `a[0]` then returns a [`Char`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/index.html). [`Char`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/index.html) on the other hand returns its character value when calling `toInt()`, check also the [documentation of `toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/to-int.html).

So your code commented:

```
val a =  "1" // a is a String
val b = a[0] // b is a Char
val c = b.toInt() // c is (an Int representing) the character value of b
```

If you just want to return the number you rather need to parse it or use any of the answers you like the most of: [How do I convert a Char to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592167/how-do-i-convert-a-char-to-int)
(one simple way being `b.toString().toInt()`).

Answer (score 0):

a is String,
when you get a[index] return type is char,
in kotlin char.toInt method return ASCII code of the character and it's 49

if you want to get the integer value of "1" just use toString method

```
val a =  "1"
val b = a[0].toString()
val c = b.toInt()       
println(c)

prints:1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `a` is a `String`, but `String`. `String` is under the hood an `Array of Char`. And by accessing your `String` using `a[0]` operator, you get first element of this Char Array. So you get Char `'1'`, not String `"1"`. And now, when you run `'1'.toInt()` function on `Char` - it will return ASCII code of that `Char`. When you run `"1".toInt()` on String - it will convert this String into Int "1". When you need to get Int value of first letter in your String, you need to convert it first into String:

```
val a = "123"
val b = a[0].toString() // returns first Char of String "123" and converts to String
val c = b.toInt()       // returns Int: 1
```

or in one line:

```
"123"[0].toString().toInt()
```