# Why the value of int variable changes after converting it to string index to int?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

```
fun main(){
    val num=348597
    println(num.toString()[0].toInt())
}
```

I should be getting 3 as the output but I'm getting 51 instead.

Does anyone know why, or what I can do instead to get 3 as the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a Char to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592167/how-do-i-convert-a-char-to-int)

Comment: @DrawnRacoon no

Answer (score 2):

`num.toString()` gives you `"348597"`. Taking `[0]` from it returns the first Char `'3'` which is a 16-bit unicode character value. Calling `toInt()` just converts the character value to an integer. In unicode the codepoints < 128 are the same as in ASCII and 51 is the value for the character '3'.

To get the character as a string representing "3", change `toInt()` to `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, I found the easy way how to solve this problem. I was getting 51 because I was converting char to int directly and it was returning ASCII value or shit instead. So here is the code:

```
fun main(){
val num=348597
//use Character.getNumericValue() instead

println(Character.getNumericValue(num.toString()[0])) }
```

[I found the answer here.](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-char-to-int)