# How do I convert a digit Char (0-9) to its numeric value?

Tags: kotlin

`Char.toInt()` returns the ASCII code of the character, rather than its numeric value. So how do I convert the Char to an integer with the correct numeric value instead?

Comment: On JVM there is `java.lang.Character.getNumericValue()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char/21441921#21441921

Comment: I think that the linked dup question is more specific and is unappropriately titled to close this one as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

You can create an extension on the Char class which substracts 48 from the ASCII code returned by `toInt()`. This will give you the proper numerical value of the character!

```
fun Char.getNumericValue(): Int {
    if (this !in '0'..'9') {
        throw NumberFormatException()
    }
    return this.toInt() - '0'.toInt()
}
```

Comment: This is technically incorrect because `isDigit` will return `true` for characters which are not necessarily `0-9`. `١`, the character `'ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ONE' (U+0661)`, **is a digit**, but `toInt() - 48` will return 1585 instead. You may want to use `this in '0'..'9'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer according to your feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You could also convert it to a `String` and then use `toInt()` which might be more obvious.

```
fun Char.getNumericValue(): Int {
    if (!isDigit()) {
        throw NumberFormatException()
    }
    return this.toString().toInt()
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but I suspect it's not as efficient if I need to run the operation a large number of times? Please correct me if I'm wrong!