# Convertion from char to int : why (int)givenString.charAt(2) give 48 with givenString = "11001"?

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion, int

Here was my problem : I wanted to convert a char into an int from a string using the following code :

```
String s = "11001";
int charAt2 = (int)s.charAt(2); //Why this gives 48 ???
System.out.println("charAt2 = "+charAtI);
```

I get on the terminal: 48. Why? That's what I would like to understand.

I have already found a great fix for my problem on Stack Overflow thanks to dasblinkenlight's link [type conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)). As I think it can be useful for someone else, here is the fixed version that perfectly works. I use the method `Character.digit( char c, int i)` that give an int from the char `c` in the radix `i` to do the conversion.

```
String s = "11001";
int charAt2 = Character.digit(s.charAt(2), 2); //radix 2 here
System.out.println("charAt2 = "+charAt2);
```

On the terminal  : 0. This works.

Comment: [Java: parse int value from a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Complete final answer :

```java
String s = "11001";
int charAt2 = (int)s.charAt(2); //Why this gives 48 ???
System.out.println("charAt2 = "+charAtI);
```

**A quick reminder**: In this situation, 11001 is a **String** representing a number in radix 2 (binary). In the more common radix 10 (decimal) we use everyday, (binary) 11001  => (decimal) 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 25.

**Possible confusions**: Do not confuse. Here we don't want to convert the String "11001" into a character by returning his [ASCII code](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), we want to convert the char 0 located at the index 2 of the string "11**0**01" into a number in radix 10, namely 0.

**NB**: Realize that the function [String.charAt(x)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) returns the character located at the String's specified index, with indexes starting from zero.

**Answer**: The code above return 48 instead of 0 because the (int) conversions happen after the s.chatAt(2) which returns the char "0" from the String s="11001". This char 0 is then converted into an int. Due to the ASCII representation of char, the char "0" is represented by the int 48 and is converted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is just a smaller `int` with fancy printing. When you convert it to an `int` you lose this fancy printing and just print the Unicode value of the character. The unicode value of **the character 0** is 48.

Comment: That make sens, I will have a look to unicode property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`s.charAt(2)` will give you `'0'`, the character `0`, NOT the number `0`. The [ascii char code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `'0'` is `48`.

Comment: While true, it is not about index at ASCII but Unicode Table.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse a char to an int, you get the index of the char in the 
[ASCII-Table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html).

Digits start with `0` at index `48` which is why `(int)'0'` returns 48.
As the indexes for numbers increment proportional to the numbers, you could use

```
int charAt2 = (int)s.charAt(2) - 48;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "11001";
int charAt2 = Integer.valueOf(""+s.charAt(2));
System.out.println("charAt2 = "+charAt2);
```

a possible way is to do this. valueOf converts a String to int, ""+aChar is a quick and dirty way to convert a char to String