# function to get second largest digit from a string

Tags: java, math, numbers, digits

I have to write a function that accepts a string and returns the second highest numerical digit in the user input as an integer. These are the rules I have to follow:

- Inputs with no numerical digits should return -1
- Inputs with only one numerical digit should return -1
- Non-numeric characters should be ignored
- Each numerical input should be treat individually, meaning in the event of a joint highest digit then the second highest digit will also be the highest digit

My code:

```
public static int secondDigit(String input) {

    try {
        int userInput = Integer.parseInt(input);

        char[] array = input.toCharArray();

        int biggest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int secondBiggest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Array: "+array[i]);

            for(int j = 0; j < array[i]; j++)
            {
                if(array[i] > biggest) 
                {
                    secondBiggest = biggest;
                    biggest = array[i];
                }
                else if(array[i] > secondBiggest && array[i] != biggest)
                {
                    secondBiggest = array[i];
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(secondBiggest);

        return userInput;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("-1");

    }
    return -1;
    // Your code goes here
}
```

"abc:1231234" should return 3
"123123" should return 3

Currently this is the code and it returns 51 when i give it an input of "123123".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is *almost* correct, the only problem is that what you print is the char at that position, the char is `'3'` and has an [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of `51`. To fix this you need to [parse an int from the char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a function to get the n-th biggest int?

Iterate over your array, if you find an int add it to an ArrayList. Then sort the ArrayList using Collections.

Now, you can grab the second-biggest (or nth-biggest) by accessing that position of your sorted ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from the ascii value to the numeric value you can substract the value of the character '0'.

```
int decimalValue = asciiValue - '0';
```

If you use a Stream to solve your problem, the solution would be very concise:

```
    public static int secondDigit(String input) {
        return input.chars() // Get the Stream from your input
                .filter(i -> i >= '0' && i <= '9')  // Filter non-numeric values
                .boxed()  // Convert to Integer to sort the Stream
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // Sort in descending order
                .skip(1)  // Skip the maximum to get the second value
                .map(i -> i - '0') // Convert the ascii value to decimal
                .findFirst()  // Get the second maximum value
                .orElse(-1);  // If not exists, returns the -1 value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with luk2302 as if you compare a char with an int. In this case, you should use         `Character.getNumericValue()` if you want to convert, say '6', to the integer 6.