# Why I am getting weird answers?

Tags: java, stack

This code is about evaluation of Postfix expression using stack.

**Main** class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        Solution r = new Solution();
        System.out.println(r.evaluatePostFix(s));
    }
}
```

**Solution** class

```
public class Solution {
    public static int evaluatePostFix(String S) {
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
        int c1, c2;
        int op = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
            char c = S.charAt(i);
            switch(c) {
                case '+':
                    c1 = (int) st.pop();
                    c2 = (int) st.pop();
                    op = c2 + c1;
                    st.push((char) op);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    c1 = (int) st.pop();
                    c2 = (int) st.pop();
                    op = c2 - c1;
                    st.push((char) op);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    c1 = (int) st.pop();
                    c2 = (int) st.pop();
                    op = c2 * c1;
                    st.push((char) op);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    c1 = (int) st.pop();
                    c2 = (int) st.pop();
                    op = c2 / c1;
                    st.push((char) op);
                    break;
                default:
                    st.push(c);
            }

            System.out.println(st);
        }

        return st.peek();
    }
}
```

What's going wrong?
For input `345+*`, I got:

```
[3]
[3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, i]
[ᓫ]
5355
```

but 27 is expected!

Comment: [parsing - Java: parse int value from a char - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Comment: This is a *great* opportunity to start using a debugger to step through the code line by line and observe its behaviors and values.  When you do this, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the exact values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @David Can't say that op didn't try. The other problem is that java prints a char value and an int value in an array the same way.

Comment: (in retrospect op probably want double, if there's a division too.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: parse int value from a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Comment: @user202729  If you don't mind, can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to convert it to integer value before doing arithmetic on it...