# How do I convert character to a string

Tags: java, types

When I run my code, the error I get says "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to a string"

```
public class Credit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long numberLong = Comp122.getLong("Number: ");
        String number = numberLong + "";
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(0)) * 2 + Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(1)) * 2);
        System.out.println("VISA");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So then you googled this error message and got some results on how to solve it, so what did not work out?

Comment: I did and it told me that it needs to be converted to a string first. I thought I did this but it still gives me the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: parse int value from a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968323/java-parse-int-value-from-a-char)

Comment: Your issue are `Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(0))` and `Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(1))`, but that approach is incorrect. See the linked question and its answer to see how it is done correctly.

Comment: When I look at your code, I wonder why you even care to convert to String and back again. What is the problem that you are really trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is actually `int` that holds ASCII number of the given character. So to transform e.g. character `5` to int value, you have to find difference between `(char)5` and `(char)0`.

```
public class Credit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long numberLong = 123456789L;
        String numberStr = String.valueOf(numberLong);
        System.out.println(toInt(numberStr, 0) * 2 + toInt(numberStr, 1) * 2);
        System.out.println("VISA");
    }

    private static int toInt(String numberStr, int index) {
        return numberStr.charAt(index) - '0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question title:

`Character.toString(char)`

This converts a char to a String.

To answer what you are trying to do:

`Character.digit(char,int)`

Converts a character to the value of the digit it represents in the specified base. In your case you are using base 10.